# How to change the content of argv in C?

Tags: c

I have been trying to search around the net but still couldn't find anything about it
I would like to do something like increase the file name,

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[]){

char charArray = {argv[1]};
char * string[] = {"-0001.c"};

int i = 0;

strcat(charArray[0] , string[0]);

puts(charArray[0]);

return 0;

}
```

so as expected, I execute it as

*./file test*

the output is

test-0001.c

what if I want to increase the number?

so that it can print out the following

*test-0001.c*

*test-0002.c*

*test-0003.c*

by using while loop?

Comment: Why NOT use a new buffer, like char buffer[512], or allocate a block of memory?

Comment: Modifying the args in `argv` in-place is probably a really bad idea. You really can't know how much spaces is allocated to each argument in advance&mdash;and likely, it's allocated *exactly enough*. And even if it worked, it wouldn't be portable.

Comment: Adding to jpaugh, you could easily get a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Your program as currently written should not currently work. Try turning on warnings and fixing them. (with the compiler flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for GCC or clang)

That said, I'd use a variable-length array and `sprintf`:

```
for(int counter = 1; counter < 10000; counter++) {
    char filename[strlen(argv[1]) + 8];
    sprintf(filename, "%s-%04d.c", argv[1], counter);
    // do something with filename
}
```